# Express route parsing hit routes it should not

Tags: javascript, regex, express, routes

I have the following two route:

```
router.get('/:postId([0-9]*)', handler) 
router.get('/:postId([0-9]*)/like', handler)
```

The first route should capture only urls like `/posts/4352/`, but not `/posts/3422/like`. However it does. I have tried in the [official route tester](http://forbeslindesay.github.io/express-route-tester/) for express and there it works as expected. ( Try to paste `/posts/:postId([0-9]*)` and `/posts/2/like`. You will see it doesn't match.)

What could cause in my case this false match?

Note: I know if I change the order than it will work, but I am curious why this is happening.

Answer (score -1):

Flip the ordering, it will match on a first hit basis unless next() is used it will not look for another match

Comment: As I mentioned, I know it will fix it. I want to know the _why_ not the _how_.

Comment: As I perhaps badly worded this works like a case statement that it will match and stop at a first correct match. so as [0-9]* which is actually a single number then anything in regex compared to ([0-9]*) which is any amount of numbers.